# How are topics and nodes connected?

Tags: python, ros

I'm pretty new to ROS programming, This question might seem silly but can someone please clear this one for me? It is really bothering me.

```
simple_publisher = rospy.Publisher('topic_1', String, queue_size = 10)
```

the line above creates a publisher object which takes string type messages for transfer under the `topic_1` name

```
rospy.init_node('node_1', anonymous = False)
```

Initialized the node for publisher

```
topic1_content = "my first ROS topic"
```

have my content for transfer ready

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        simple_publisher.publish(topic1_content)
```

In this bit how does the program know that the `topic1_content` that was published using `simple_publisher` is from the `node_1`. How is `node_1` getting connected to `topic_1`?

Can we only make 1 node per program i.e. we can only run `rospy.init_node` only once?

Comment: Are you using ROS 1 or ROS 2?  If you are using ROS 1 all the nodes are "indexed" by ROS Master Nodes and the communication is based on Subscriber Publisher Architecture. You could theoretically have, has many nodes as you want, with all talking with each other.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The thing that I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around is that, if topics are the informaton highways through which our data passes, a publisher is a source and the subscriber is the destination. When we do rospy.init_node() and eventually <publisher_object>.publish()  how does the ROS system know that the topic initialized in the <publisher_object> and the node initialized by rospy.init_node() are the connected; Meaning, how does the topic know that the node whose information i'm supposed to carry is 'node_1' and not some other node. Hope u get what i mean.

Comment: Read this document linked. Especially the ROS Computation graph part. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts

Comment: @ichherzcplusplus Thanks a lot. I'll make sure to go through it.